# Python:How to store multiple function call of same function in Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

This is a simple function,i need to store all value of function call in a dictionary

```
 def func1(a,b):
        return a+b

    func1(5,7)
    func1(7,7)
    func1(8,7)
    func1(3,5)
    func1(9,8)
    func1(11,7)
```

OUTPT={1:12,2:14,3:15} And so on....

Comment: What part do you need help with? and what have you tried so far? Please share your code attempt(s).

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking here - in the code section you define a function, and then execute it a number of times with seemingly random parameters - later you say that you want the output to be stored in a dictionary. What's the issue here?

Comment: i am not understanding how to dtore each output in a dictionary,can give hint or solution @ThomasKimber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
d = {1 : func1(5,7) , 
     2 : func1(7,7) , 
     3 : func1(8,7) , 
     4 :   func1(3,5) }
```

The functions will be evaluated when you inspect the contents of the dictionary.

Comment: What do you mean by "inspect"? You state "The functions will be evaluated when you inspect the contents of the dictionary", but they are evaluated when the dictionary is created.

Comment: Yes, loose language on my part there - I just meant to say you can create this dictionary using the raw function-calls, only learning what they finally evaluate to after looking inside that dictionary to find the values.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like so:

```py
output = {}
values = [(5, 7), (7, 7), ....]
for k, (n, m) in enumerate(values, 1):
    output[f"{k}"] = func1(n, m)

print(output)
```

Comment: no,i want the function call  and not val

Comment: @Raju You'll need to clarify your question then please, because in the question you said that you wish to store the "value of function call in a dictionary", which is what this answer does